# Code compiles on GCC 6.2.0 built by MinGW-W64 when it shouldn't

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, mingw-w64

This sample code should not be valid in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Test
{
public:
    void func();
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(Test::func), //error, use &Test::func
                              void(Test::*)(void)>::value << std::endl;
}
```

But compiles in `gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 Project) 6.2.0`,
and outputs `true` when using whichever `Test::func` or `&Test::func`.

Yet it rightfully fails to compile with any other compiler, or even with GCC 6.2.0 [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',sourcez:AQ4YgSwOwYwGwK4BMCmwA8ED2BnALgE4oCGAtgHwBQo408ya6eAngA4oD6hxEeOVNaqHjEcOYABUU%2BISADes4KwQAjOBBgAuRTQBuWCEmAAzBLAAUASgDcigL63F0PMFI8oVxQpo18STZowWAgu6OjAfgEQOBw4ZCjoqPAs7OZS%2BAGmsJYANMAA9PkoBARYBHkIOGgAZOl4mWYwOj4trW2g%2BoZp0vWaAFSW5p1IluQBusSIjOGRmihQSHC2NHZAA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

What's wrong with MinGW-W64? `MinGW-W64 GCC 5.3.0` also compiles this.

Comment: Submit a bug report?

Comment: Not sure what you want us to do about it lol

Comment: This is not a new behavior on mingw. It is probably there to support some windows header.